# In a HTML form how can I do to access via PHP a option from select tag by optgroup?

Tags: php, html, forms, select, optgroup

In a HTML form how can I do to access via PHP a option from select tag by optgroup?
It's possible?

It would be like this:

```
<select name="est" id="est">
  <optgroup name="G1" label="Group 1">
    <option>Opção 1.1</option>
  </optgroup> 
  <optgroup name="G2" label="Group 2">
    <option>Opção 2.1</option>
    <option>Opção 2.2</option>
  </optgroup>
</select>
<?php if($name == "G2") { do something } ?>
```

Comment: optgroups aren't visible to the server, they're just used to group options on the client.

Answer (score 1):

Include the optgroup name in the option values.

```
<select name="est" id="est">
  <optgroup name="G1" label="Group 1">
    <option value="G1-1">Opção 1.1</option>
  </optgroup> 
  <optgroup name="G2" label="Group 2">
    <option value="G2-1">Opção 2.1</option>
    <option value="G2-2">Opção 2.2</option>
  </optgroup>
</select>
```

Then when you're processing the form data, you can check the beginning of the value.

```
list($name, $value) = explode("-", $_POST["est"]));
if ($name == "G2") {
    // do something
}
```

Comment: Is the PHP code in the script that processes the form submission?

Comment: No. It is inside the HTML

Comment: That makes no sense. Inputs aren't available until you submit the form. What are you trying to do with the optgroup before the form is submitted?

Comment: If you need to process it before submitting, you need to use client-side JavaScript, not PHP.

Comment: I solved it! It's only substr($value,0,2). Thanks a lot!

Comment: That won't work if you have more than 9 groups. `G10` is `subtr($value, 0, 3)`

Comment: I only have two groups.

Comment: Maybe you do, but the next person who follows this will have more.